Google.Cloud.Retail.V2.ProductServiceClient, SetInventoryAsync throws invalid operation exception
I am following this Google's tutorial and it is failing in the operation.PollUntilCompleted() operation.
The exception that I receive is
'operation.Result' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'    Google.Cloud.Retail.V2.SetInventoryResponse {System.InvalidOperationException}

with the error message
"Operation has not completed." 
Here is the code that I executed from the tutorial. I leave it here for convenience:
    /// <summary>
    /// Call the Retail API to set product inventory.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="product">The actual product.</param>
    public static void SetProductInventory(string productName)
    {
        var setInventoryRequest = GetSetInventoryRequest(productName);
        var client = ProductServiceClient.Create();
        var operation = client.SetInventory(setInventoryRequest);

        Console.WriteLine("Set inventory. Please, wait.");
        Console.WriteLine();

        operation.PollUntilCompleted();   // <<<<< This line causes the exception.
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// The set inventory tutorial class.
/// </summary>
public static class SetInventoryTutorial
{
    [Runner.Attributes.Example]
    public static void PerformSetInventoryOperation()
    {
        string projectId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_PROJECT_ID");

        // Create product.
        Product createdProduct = CreateProductSample.CreateRetailProductWithFulfillment(projectId);

        // Set inventory for product.
        SetInventorySample.SetProductInventory(createdProduct.Name);

        // Get product.
        Product product = GetProductSample.GetRetailProduct(createdProduct.Name);

        Console.WriteLine($"Product Price Info: {product.PriceInfo}");
        Console.WriteLine();

        // Delete product.
        DeleteProductSample.DeleteRetailProduct(createdProduct.Name);
    }


I can successfully create the product. When I try to set the inventory, it throws the exception on the operation.PollUntilCompleted() line.
Can you please advise how to proceed?
Thank you in advance.
---  Update ---
Here is the repo with a sample app that reproduces the same exception's stack trace.
(Sorry I pasted the wrong information previously.) Here is the exception's stack trace.
I tried another method, AddLocalInventoriesAsync, and it throws the same error message.

Could you include the full stack trace?

Sure, I have just uploaded it. Thanks.

That stack trace looks like it's got all kinds of things which aren't in the tutorial at all - that's an ASP.NET Core stack trace, and the tutorial is just a console app, isn't it?

Correct.
Authentication credentials, environment variables and all the stuff was applied and are working. I grantted more permissions than I actually needed.

But my point is that you've presented code from the tutorial as if that's the code that's failing, but it looks like actually it's a completely different codebase where you're observing the error. Please provide a [mcve] of the code that's not working.

I'm not sure you've been reading my comments carefully. I haven't said anything about IAM permissions etc, nor questioned whether you've got that set up appropriately. I've said that the code you've included in the question doesn't appear to be the code that has created the stack trace you've posted. It's very hard to diagnose an error when we can't see the code that's creating it. Please, please post a [mcve] that produces the error you're seeing.

Thank you Jon for responding. This sample app requires Google Account, Retail Search API enabled and read and write permissions (IAM) to fully reproduce the issue. If you are OK with this, I will post the app here in my next comment.
Thank you.

No, please don't put it in a comment - edit your question instead. (And yes, I have all of that set up. To give context, I'm a maintainer of the Google Cloud client libraries.)

The link that you've labeled as "exception's stack trace" isn't a stack trace. It's a screenshot of the debugger, but it doesn't include the actual stack trace. This sort of thing makes it so much harder to help you. Additionally, it would be much better if a minimal example were in the question instead of in a separate repo. I'll clone your repo to try to reproduce it, but please read https://jonskeet.uk/links/stack-hints

I've just run the code in your repo, and it worked fine - no exceptions. Is that the actual code that's causing an issue? (Again, it's completely different from your earlier stack trace.)

If you're only seeing the exception in the debugger when inspecting the Result property of operation, I'm not surprised that you're seeing that, and it's not a bug. The initial operation isn't complete, so using operation.Result correctly throws an exception. But that's not the same as the code itself throwing an exception.

You are right, Jon. We were only seeing the exception in the debbuger when inspecting the Result property.
On the other hand, we were also working with AddLocalInventories but we missunderstood how to check the updated inventories in ours Product catalog. We could finally figure out how to use (and check) both methods with your advise.
Thank you very much!

Okay, I'll add that as an answer.

After back and forth in the comments, it turns out that the code itself was not throwing an exception. Instead, an exception was only seen in the debugger, when examining the Result property of an incomplete operation. That's behaving exactly as documented - when an operation hasn't completed, attempting to access its Result property throws InvalidOperationException.
The easiest way to see the result of the operation after it's completed is to use the return value of PollUntilCompleted:
operation = operation.PollUntilCompleted();

After this statement has completed, examining operation in the debugger should show the result.
In general, I would advise against being worried about exceptions which are only shown when examining properties in the debugger - unless your code evaluates the same property, you won't encounter that exception.
